# Finite CDGA model for a compact manifold

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, differential-graded-algebras

Is it true that a compact smooth manifold always has a finite-dimension commutative dg algebra model?

Same question can be asked about compact CW complexes.

More generally, is it true that a CW complex of finite type always has a CDGA model of finite type?

PS. I always assume the coefficients are rationals or any other field of characteristic zero.

Comment: The main problem here is when H^1 is non-trivial.

Comment: For me it is the same thing. I mean graded commutative if this is the question, which is the same as commutative  in the symmetric monoidal  category of dg spaces.

Comment: A positive answer to the third question implies a positive answer to the second, because we can always truncate a CDGA at the top degree where cohomology is non-trivial. A positive answer to the second implies a positive answer to the first, because any compact smooth manifold admits a handle decomposition.

Comment: Do you work with rational coefficients? If not, then the quotient $M$ of $S^3$ by the standard $\mathbb{Z}/3$-action with $\mathbb{F}_3$-coefficients is a counterexample. Here the Massey-product $\langle x,x,x\rangle \in H_2$ is nonzero, but for commutative DGAs such a Massey-product would always be zero (choose the same chain bounding $x*x$ on the left and on the right).

Comment: HenrikRuping, I do assume the coefficients are rational numbers. It is a question in Rational Homotopy Theory. I updated the question.

Comment: The answer to the first question is yes in the simply-connected case, by Lambrechts-Stanley: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0701309. But judging by your first comment, you seem to be aware of this.

Comment: @MarkGrant an alternative argument for a simply connected $n$-complex (with no assumption on Poincare duality): take a minimal model for the space, and set all elements strictly above degree $n$ to 0; we get an induced map to the space that is an iso on cohomology everywhere except in deg $n$, where we have introduced some kernel by getting rid of the deg $n+1$ elements. Introduce elements in deg $n-1$ to kill this kernel, and map them to 0. Then again set all elements in degree $>n$ to 0. This gives a finite model; note that in the presence of $H^1$ we might have to repeat the last step.